# VSC not showing if one variable is greater than another variable

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3BuJ.png)

I am starting out on my python journey and learned of VSC. Everything so far seems to marry up with python in command prompt, except comparing one variable against another.
Is this something VSC isn't capable of, do I have to adjust a setting, is the code wrong?
Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5fWc.png)
This is the answer I was expecting.

```
a = 5
b = 15
a > b
false
```

Comment: in your second image you have used a Python REPL, the first image is a Python script

Answer (score 0):

Your code is executing correctly.

But it is not a command prompt so that you don't see the results on your terminal.
If you want to see the results on your terminal, in VSCode and other editors, you should print out the result, otherwise, they won't show up in terminal.

```py
a = 5
b = 15
print(a > b) # prints false
```

---

#### SideNote:

There are some VSCode extensions that automatically executes your code and prints out the results next to values/statements.
I am not sure how capable or reliable they are. you should search them and try them out yourself.